# NotImplementedError: in LSTM model

Tags: lstm

iam new to this forum and ML,

Iam writing the following code

```
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
```

on running the code i get the following error, can any one please help me

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Comment: Are you using a gpu or a cpu?

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the numpy to version = 1.19.5. After that run it.

Comment: Why would that help? Please read [answer].

Comment: Admittedly, as I am aware of this issue for some time, I know that this could be a solution. However, as many do not know, in particular when answering, please make sure that you do create a good answer, so that everybody understands what you wrote here, and explain/motivate the choice for your answer, as @Chris mentioned above.